# How to masked network directory with Active Directory & IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, iis-7, network-share

Departments within our organization have file directories on our IIS7 2008 R2 server similar to `\\apollo\marketing.oems`, which are outward facing for clients. We would like to create masked directories for quicker access like `\\marketing` that would point to `\\apollo\marketing.oems`. I've done research and have not come across any real answers, although I know it's possible

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just create a new website which:

- points to the marketing.oems folder as its physical path.
- uses the host header "marketing"

Then, create a DNS alias "marketing" that points the hostname marketing to the IP address used by the server.